# Getting error 'ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out' when using GIT clone

Tags: git-bash

Use the below Steps:

1. ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
2. vi ~/.ssh/config
   Host github.com
   Hostname ssh.github.com
   Port 443
3. ssh -T git@github.com
4. git clone git@github.com:
   Now you can run any git command with this CLI

Additional Document: 
**How to use git CLI into windows machine?**
step1: Download git Bash from :
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.26.2.windows.1/Git-2.26.2-64-bit.exe
2:  ssh-keygen -t rsa
3. cat id_rsa.pub from .ssh folder
4. paste the same inside github --> go to user section--> Personal Settings--> SSH and GPG Keys and paste the same inside SSH keys block. 
5. ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
6. vi ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
7. ssh -T git@github.com
8. git clone git@github.com:
Now you can run any git command with this CLI
cat